# Input validation/data filtering with Powershell

Tags: powershell, office365

I've been working on this for a little while, basically all I'm doing is grabbing the licensing from our clients' Office 365 tenant and displaying it in a more readable manner since Office 365 Powershell doesn't output subscription names in a common name. This works perfectly when every subscription is in my CSV of subscription names, however on occasions where the SKU is not in my list (brand new or legacy offerings) the licensing table doesn't populate correctly because it can't find the friendlyname in my CSV (licensing quantities don't match the subscription name because of a blank record when it failed to find the SKU).

What I'm trying to have it do is display the skupartnumber in place of the friendlyname in the event that the subscription is not in my CSV instead of breaking the output. The first snippet below is my current working script that only works if the SKU is in my CSV, the one below it is the my best attempt at trying some input validation but I just can't get it to work. Everything displays correctly except the Subscription column which is blank (I also notice that it takes about 5x as long to run as normal), I would greatly appreciate any assistance offered; thanks!

Works as long as subscription is in my CSV:

```
$sku = Get-MsolAccountSku | select-object skupartnumber,ActiveUnits,suspendedUnits,ConsumedUnits | sort-object -property skupartnumber

$skudata = import-csv -Header friendlyname,skupartnumber "C:\PShell\cspcatalogalphabet.csv" | where-object {$sku.skupartnumber -eq $_.skupartnumber} | sort-object -property skupartnumber

$result = for ($n = 0; $n -lt @($skudata).Count; $n++) {
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        Subscription = @($skudata.friendlyname)[$n]
        Active        = $sku.ActiveUnits[$n]
        Suspended     = $sku.SuspendedUnits[$n]
        Assigned      = $sku.ConsumedUnits[$n]
    }
}

$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# Output:
Subscription                 Active Suspended Assigned
------------                 ------ --------- --------
Microsoft Flow Free           10000         0        1
Power Bi (Free)             1000000         0        1
Microsoft Teams Exploratory     100         0        6
```

My best attempt at input validation which results in no data being read into $skulist.Subscription:

```
$sku = Get-MsolAccountSku | select-object skupartnumber,ActiveUnits,suspendedUnits,ConsumedUnits

$skulist = import-csv -Header friendlyname,skupartnumber "C:\PShell\cspcatalogalphabet.csv"

$skuname = for ($c = 0; $c -lt @($sku).count; $c++) {
    if ($sku.skupartnumber[$c] -in $skulist.skupartnumber) {
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            Subscription =  $skulist.friendlyname | where-object {$sku.skupartnumber[$c] -eq $skulist.skupartnumber}
        }
    }
    else {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Subscription = @($sku.skupartnumber)[$c]
        }
    }
}

$table = for ($n = 0; $n -lt @($sku).Count; $n++) {
        [PsCustomObject]@{
        Subscription =  @($skuname.Subscription)[$n]
        Active        = $sku.ActiveUnits[$n]
        Suspended     = $sku.SuspendedUnits[$n]
        Assigned      = $sku.ConsumedUnits[$n]
    }
}

$table | format-table -AutoSize

# Output:
Subscription  Active Suspended Assigned
------------  ------ --------- --------
               10000         0        1
             1000000         0        1
                 100         0        6

# An example of data I am grabbing from our clients' accounts:
$sku = Get-MsolAccountSku | select-object skupartnumber,ActiveUnits,suspendedUnits,ConsumedUnits
$sku
# Output:
SkuPartNumber     ActiveUnits SuspendedUnits ConsumedUnits
-------------     ----------- -------------- -------------
FLOW_FREE               10000              0             1
POWER_BI_STANDARD     1000000              0             1
TEAMS_EXPLORATORY         100              0             6
```

Comment: How do you want to handle the SKUs that are not in your CSV? Ignore? Show their ID? Show a custom label a la "PRODUCT UNKNOWN"?

Comment: Hey Mathias, I'd like it to just display the SKU ID ($sku.skupartnumber) if it's not found in my CSV!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of relying on the two arrays being *aligned* - that is, index `$n` in `$sku` *must* correspond to the item at index `$n` in `$skulist` for you code to work - you'll want to be able to resolve a value in `$skulist` based on the *actual* `$SKU.SkuPartNumber` value instead.

So how does one do that?!

Feed your `$skulist` into a `[hashtable]` instead:

```
$skulist = @{}

Import-Csv -Header friendlyname,skupartnumber "C:\PShell\cspcatalogalphabet.csv" |ForEach-Object {
  $skulist[$_.skupartnumber] = $_.friendlyname
}
```

And then iterate over `$skudata` like this (notice there's no need for a `for(;;)` loop anymore, we don't need to care about array alignment!):

```
foreach($skuEntry in $sku){
  [pscustomobject]@{
    Subscription  = if($skuList.ContainsKey($skuEntry.SKUPartNumber){$skuList[$skuEntry.SKUPartNumber]}else{$skuEntry.SKUPartNumber})
    Active        = $skuEntry.ActiveUnits
    Suspended     = $skuEntry.SuspendedUnits
    Assigned      = $skuEntry.ConsumedUnits
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, this is exactly what I was thinking of! I always knew that relying on the aligned arrays wasn't the way to go but I wasn't sure how to search them otherwise. I do have a quick question: is ContainsKey going to match the input exactly? There are many similar skupartnumber IDs and don't want any issues arising if Microsoft adds, for instance, FLOW_FREE_VERSION on top of the existing skupartnumber FLOW_FREE.

Comment: I was able to answer my last question myself by testing with some garbage input in my CSV, I think this solves the problem I was having with this filtering. Appreciate the assistance!

Comment: @phoneybaloneypshell Great to hear you figured it out! :-) It won't be a problem in this scenario, since `ContainsKey()` on a hashtable instantiated with `@{}` in PowerShell will compare the same was as `-eq` does - so for string keys, it's _case-insensitive_, but _exact_ - `@{"FLOW_FREE"=''}.ContainsKey("flow_free")` holds, but `@{"FLOW_FREE"=''}.ContainsKey("flow_free_version")` would not